# Why jQuery-migrate in not replacing depreciated functions directly in the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-migrate

Im using jQuery-migrate on a big project. I corrected all the warnings I could but now the warnings are inside libraries.

Some libraries are not updated anymore so I can't update them to make them work with jQuery-3.3.1.
Also, I can't replace the depreciated functions directly in the libraires because it is creating errors.

So I think that I'll keep jQuery-migrate in my project.

**My question is** : If jQuery-migrate is able to correct the depreciated functions when called, why it can not correct them directly in the code ?

Comment: What were versions that worked before upgrade? What methods are breaking?

Comment: I went from jQuery 1.7.2 to jQuery 1.12.4 with jQuery-migrate. I corrected all the warnings and then delete jQuery migrate. Now, I'm doing the same process but going from 1.12.4 to 3.3.1.

Comment: A lot of methods are breaking because i'm using maybe 20 different old librairies. It's a project from 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does not lend itself to static code analysis.

Say you needed to replace the `foo` function.

That would be fairly trivial if the code that called it was simply:

```
something.foo();
```

It becomes rather harder if it is:

```
function call(bar, method) {
    bar[method]();
}

call(something, "foo");
```

… and even harder if the logic needed to get there was more complicated.

---

Creating `something.foo` so it *just exists* if anything try to access it at runtime is much simpler.

Comment: So, in my case do you think that the best solution is to keep jQuery-migrate ?

Comment: I don't know enough about your problem to say.

Comment: Added complexity would be to make deprecated or changed methods compatible with higher version seeing as they were deprecated or changed for a reason

Comment: @freedomn-m — No! Absolutely not. Versions of jQuery which need jQuery migrate don't get security updates any more.

Comment: @Quentin the point being that the 3rd party libraries are not being updated either - so if you are running plugins that use older jQuery code, it’s probably better to update them or switch to an alternative that *is* kept up-to-date.

Comment: My problem is that it would be very long to correct around 20 different librairies because of depreciated functions. Some of them need updates, others need a replacement, etc.

Comment: @freedomn-m — Changing the third party libraries is probably the sensible way forward. Keeping unsupported core jQuery isn't.

Comment: @William — jQuery 3.0 came out on June 9, 2016. Quite of lot of that time 1.x and 2.x were still supported. There's been plenty of time. The problem is that the problem has been ignored until now. It's only going to get worse.

Comment: I agree, but this is not my project it is from the company in which I work. I have been working there for only 2 weeks hehe. Ok so I'll try to update/replace/find a solution for every librairie. And if I see that this is too much time consuming, I'll keep Jquery-migrate.